# Trim characters

Tags: sql

All,
I have 2 values as below in a table.

```
ID      Name  
1    Justs_S01_3456
2    S01_56788
```

The output I want is below.

```
ID      Name             NewName
1    Justs_S01_3456      S01_3456
2    S01_56788           S01_56788
```

I tried using CHARINDEX and other functions,but I am not getting the desired output.
Can some one please help me?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: what is the common pattern of trimming? Does it start with `S`? `S01`? `S01_`? Or should everything up until and including the 2nd underscore from the end be deleted?

Comment: John, do you try query?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you could use:

```
select t.*, stuff(name, 1, charindex('S01_', name) - 1, '') as newname
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=884c08c7477122fc22f18c39f0db5bc3) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String functions`.
The `PATINDEX() function` returns the position of a pattern in a string (beginning position 'S01' in the Name)
AND using `SUBSTRING function` you can extract the string from `S01 position` to the end of string:

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING(Name,PATINDEX('%S01%',Name),len(Name)) As NewName from Table
```